# Plot a space curve and its curvature

Tags: plotting, differential-geometry

The vector is `< te^t, e^-t, Sqrt [2]t >`, where `-5 <= t <= 5`
I have to plot the space curve and its curvature function `k(t)`.

I already found the curvature, but do not know how to plot the space curve and its curvature function.

Curvature is:

```
Sqrt[2 E^(-2 t) + (3 + 2 t)^2 + (2 Sqrt[2] E^t + Sqrt[2] E^t t)^2]/[(2 + E^(-2 t) + (E^t + E^t t)^2)^(3/2)]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ArcCurvature` is already built-in to Mathematica, so there is no need to compute curvature manually:

```
f[t_] := {t Exp[t], Exp[-t], Sqrt[2] t}
Simplify@ArcCurvature[f[t], t]
Plot[%, {t, -3, 3}]
ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, -1, 1}]
```

which produces

$$\kappa(t)=\frac{e^{2 t} \sqrt{2 e^{4 t} (t+2)^2+e^{2 t} (2 t+3)^2+2}}{\left(e^{4 t} (t+1)^2+2 e^{2
   t}+1\right)^{3/2}}$$

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
fun = {u E^u, E^-u, Sqrt[2] u};

cur = Sqrt[2/E^(2*u) + (3 + 2*u)^2 + (2*Sqrt[2]*E^u + Sqrt[2]*E^u*u)^2]/
   (2 + E^(-2*u) + (E^u + E^u*u)^2)^(3/2);

plo = Plot[cur, {u, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
range = Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plo, PlotRange]];

ParametricPlot3D[fun, {u, -5, 5},
 BoxRatios -> 1,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[cur, range]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.015]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just collecting and presenting information already on the page:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r[u_] := {u E^u, E^-u, Sqrt[2] u}
ac = ArcCurvature[r[u], u] // Simplify;
max = NMaximize[ac, u];

barlegend = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, First@max}}
   , LegendMarkerSize -> 160
   , LegendLabel -> "Arc Curvature"
   , LabelStyle -> {Black, 12}
   ];

Row@{ParametricPlot3D[{r[u]}
   , {u, -3, 3}
   , PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]
   , ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, u, v}
      , ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, First@max}}][ac]])
   , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
   , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
   , ImageSize -> 300
   , PlotLabel -> "Space Curve highlighting Arc Curvature"
   , AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
   , LabelStyle -> {Black, 12}
   ]
  , Plot[ac, {u, -3, 3}
   , PlotRange -> All
   , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
   , ImageSize -> 300
   , PlotLabel -> Style["Arc Curvature", "Arial", Black, 14]
   , AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {"u", "κ[u]"}
   , LabelStyle -> {Black, 12}
   ]
  , Spacer[20]
  , barlegend
  }
```

[image]